# Windows wake up from poweroff

Tags: windows

We have a few scripts to test some power management on both Windows and Linux.

Linux sets an RTC wake alarm to power the machine on from a fully powered off state. This seems to be something entirely missing from Windows. To combat this we use a mix of WOL and networked power switches. This works to a degree but is less reliable than the Linux approach.

Is there a windows tool to do set an RTC alarm that I've missed, or is there a reason why this isn't doable on Windows.